# Text over a translucent div causes the text to be translucent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get text over a translucent div. This is in Chrome, if that's relevant (i.e. a Chrome bug). For some reason, whenever the text is on top of the div (moved there by a negative margin-top), it is also partially transparent.

HTML is as follows (this is a simplified approximation):

```
<div class="background-image-div"></div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Text goes here</p>
</div>
```

CSS is as follows (this is a simplified approximation):

```
.background-image-div {
  background: url(../images/Image.png) no-repeat right;
  opacity: .5;
}

.content {
  height: 480px;
  margin-top: -271px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

So background-image-div should absolutely be translucent, but for some reason, the text in the content div, which shouldn't be and which isn't a child of background-image-div is translucent as well. When I turn opacity off of the background-image-div, it doesn't appear to be on the content div, and likewise when I don't use negative margin-top on the content div (to push it to the same position as background-image-div), it also doesn't appear to be translucent.

What is going on exactly? As far as I can tell this is not WAD. Is it a bug in Chrome?

Comment: Just to shed some light on this, your text is not appearing translucent. It's just that it's being pulled *under* your translucent DIV, which provides somewhat of an illusion. If you put a `cursor: pointer;` on the `content` CSS, you'll notice your cursor won't change - indicating that it's underneath the background element.

Comment: @TylerRoper ~ you could have written this as an answer.

Comment: @sheriffderek I may have answered the question, however I felt it was not worthy of being written as an actual answer, being as I did not provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: When you think something may be a Bug, it's nice to really strip down the code to a smaller example that you can check in many browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/7196pa22/

Answer (score 1):

The text is not translucent. What is happening is that the translucent image is on top of your text, so you see the text lighter.

Here's a modified version of your CSS. The important addition is `position:relative` and `z-index: -1` on the `.background-image-div`

```
.content {
  height: 480px;
  margin-top: -271px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: black; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold;
}

.background-image-div {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: -1;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/EverestfromKalarPatarcrop.JPG) no-repeat right;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

On CodePen: https://codepen.io/vic3685/pen/PzdEEJ

Comment: To be clear, you must have an explicit 'position' set for an element to take into account the `z-index` value. You could also just put the text lower in the markup, and it would be "on top" by default. In general, there is probably a much better way to write this / without negative margins etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me how it works, it worked for me.

HTML

```
  <div id="picture">
    <div class="background-image-div"></div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>Text goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
top:400px;
left:200px;
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
}

.background-image-div {
/*place your image in here*/ background: url('http://hk.blouinartinfo.com/sites/default/files/1349378871-56591.jpg') no-repeat;
opacity: .5;
background-size:cover;
/*or whatever size you want*/
height:500px; 
width:500px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't describe any solution.